# Android Browser, DOM show/hide and unresponsive form elements

Tags: jquery, android, forms, dom

We're running into a bizarre android bug. We know it exists on an HTC Thunderbolt running 2.3.4. It may exist on other versions/devices.

The example:

http://jsbin.com/inupon/3

What it is:

It's some SELECT elements inside of a DOM element with the style of `display: none` upon page load (it is hidden). Via jQuery, we use `show()` to change it to `display: block`.

Nothing out of the ordinary. Works fine in nearly every device out there.

However, we're running into two issues on the HTC:

1. sometimes it takes 2 or 3 taps to actually activate the select to choose an option
2. after changing the option, the select does not update to reflect the new value even though it 'takes' it (as we can see when we actually submit the form).

I've narrowed it down to the display property. If I load the page with it already set to `display: block` (ie, not hidden) then it works just fine on that device.

Any known DOM issues with Android browsers? Or the HTC specifically?